# Navigating to the homeScreen after setting up the user's profile

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-navigation

I've figured out how to navigate from the signupScreen to homeScreen using React-navigation along with firebase-authentication but I've added an additional screen. This is the profileSetupScreen. My issue is that I can't navigate from the set-up screen to homeScreen after getting the data from the user. The finish button is suppposed to 'addData' then navigate to homeScreen but I can't figure that out.

Please ask if you need more info. Here is a portion of my code. What should I add?

```
//...
//This adds the users data onto firebase
const addData = () => {
    try {
      const docRef = addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
        nickname,
        bio,
        selectedImage,
        dbEmail,
      });
      console.log("Document written with ID:", docRef.id);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
    }
  };

  //Overall UI
  return (
//Once 'Finish' is pressed, it saves the data onto FireStore and should navigate to homeScreen
    <View style={styles.all}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Profile Setup</Text>
      <View style={styles.selectionView}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.completebtn} onPress={onSignOut}>
          <Text style={styles.backtxt}>Back</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.completebtn} onPress={addData}>
          <Text style={styles.completetxt}>Finish</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
//...
```

Comment: 1. Instead of saving userData in firestore, you should consider saving it in the userToken. That will save database requests and time. 2. You have to await addDoc and make addData async. 3. If you use React Navigation, just use the navigate() method. If you don't know how to use it, look it up in the React Navigation docs

Comment: @MaximilianDietel thanks for the suggestion, I'll try saving the userData onto a userToken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether or not `ProfileSetupScreen` is a `Screen` defined in the navigator. If it is, then the navigation framework will pass the `navigation` prop to the `ProfileSetupScreen` and you can use it as follows via the `screen props`.

```js
const ProfileSetupScreen = ({navigation}) => {

  const addData = () => {
    try {
      const docRef = addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
        nickname,
        bio,
        selectedImage,
        dbEmail,
      });
      console.log("Document written with ID:", docRef.id);
    navigation.navigate(”HomeScreen”)
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
    }
  };

  return (…)
}
```

Notice, that `navigation.navigate(”HomeScreen“)` take the name of the screen to which we want to navigate and which is defined in the navigator, thus if your Home Screen is defined there with a different name, then you need to use that name.

If your `ProfileSetupScreen` is not a screen in your navigator, then the navigation prop will not be passed to the screen.

In this case you have two choices. Either pass the navigation prop down to the component from a parent screen that is a defined screen in the navigator or use the `useNavigation` hook as follows.

```js
const ProfileSetupScreen = (props) => {
   const navigation = useNavigation()
…

}
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but it didn't exactly solve the issue correctly. After I'm done setting up it takes me to the homeScreen but I can still go back to the initial setupScreen. Maybe you misunderstood my question.

Comment: If you do not want to be able to go back to the `ProfileSetupScreen` after navigation to the `HomeScreen` you can just use `navigation.reset({index:0, routes:[{name: 'HomeScreen'}]})`

Comment: This resets the navigation state with a new route.